# Integral as a limit of an infinite sum of infinitely narrow rectangles

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, infinity

I tried to approach integrating by filling the space with infinitely many infinitely narrow rectangles.

$a$ is the left bound

$b$ is the right bound

$n$ means the number of rectangles, approaches $\infty$

$k$ means the k-th rectangle

My integral is described by the following formula:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b-a}{n} \cdot f(a + \frac{k(b-a)}{n})
$$

The rough idea in the picture below:

[image]

Let's solve for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, a = 1, b = 3

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{2k}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{2}{n+2}+\frac{2}{n+4}+\frac{2}{n+6}+ \dots\right)
$$
The sum clearly diverges, but I don't know why.. any ideas? Is this way of integrating possible? If not, why? Are my formulas correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your sum should only go up to $n$. You have otherwise properly described the right hand Riemann sum. The sum has a finite number of terms, so it does not diverge. You take the limit after you do the sum and should get $\log 3$.

Comment: $n$ approaches $\infty$ though? That's why I put it above the sum. What else should I limit $k$ to?

Comment: That is the point of the limit out front. You evaluate the sum for a given $n$, then take the limit. The sum is bounded by $2$, so the limit cannot diverge either

Comment: @MateuszSowiński $n$ approaches $\infty$, but we're dealing with a sequence of sums—with the $n$th sum having $n$ as its upper limit. You've got $k$ approaching $\infty$ in each one.

Comment: @RossMillikan I would do that if I wanted an approximation, right? I want an exact number though, that's why I'm adding an infinite amount of these rectangles

Comment: @MateuszSowiński Increasing $n$ = using more rectangles for the next sum. Increasing $k$ = counting through the $n$ rectangles for a given $n$, so $k$ only ever goes up to $n$.

Comment: But you have to do the finite sum analytically before you take the limit. If we do the same with $f(x)=1$ you get the sum of $2/n$, which sums to $2$. Then when you take the limit you still get $2$ Your sum is less.

Comment: @MateuszSowiński you get infinitely many by letting $n\rightarrow \infty$, as per the limit sign.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{2}{n} + \frac{2}{n} + \dots) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{2n}{n}) = 2$ Is this right? Basically $k$ becomes $n$ here? but what about more complex functions like $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$?